# How to map enum types to imm values in IDA

Tags: ida, idapro-sdk

I have added support for type info handling in my IDA processor, and now in the `use_regarg_type3` event, I am mapping a parameter that I know is an `enum`. But, I am unsure how to set an `imm` operand to be `enum`, as you would if you pressed m key and selected the type manually.

So, my question is what function do I call to set the op to be an `enum`, and how do I get any needed arguments for said function from the `tinfo_t` I have.

#### Edit 1

There is an `op_enum` function, but it wants `enum_t` and from the `tinfo_t` via `type.get_enum_base_type()` I get `type_t`.

#### Edit 2

I have it working using

```
qstring tname;
type.get_type_name(&tname);
enum_t enumt = get_enum(tname.c_str());
op_enum(cmd.ea, x.n, enumt, 0);
```

But, it feels wrong to have to go via a string, and a little fragile. So, now the questions is: is there a better/safer way to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you creating the enums on your own? If so, you can use the objects returned from the enum creation instead of the names.